# Using .getclass() on an interface

Tags: java

This is probably a very easy question.
Hey I'm a student and relatively new to java and I'm currently studying for a midterm that I have tomorrow. One of the practice questions I am stuck on is what happens when you have something like:

`System.out.println(interface1.getClass().getName());`

`interface1` has been declared as `interface1 = class1`. I'm pretty sure it would print "class1" and not "interface1" because `interface1` is not a class right?  but I'm not sure as the question also says that if it produces a compile time error then say so. Our professor is known for tricking us and more then once I get back a quiz and still been confused as to why I got a problem wrong.

Comment: What about you test that yourself by writing this program and executing it?

Comment: Is there more code to go with it? We don't know what `class` is.

Comment: I would have and have actually done that for many of the programs on the practice midterm but this one wasn't a program but just a question. Plus I would like to have learned a little about more about interfaces which the gentleman below me did exactly that.

Comment: And thank you Pablo for editing the code in, I should have done that myself but I rarely post on here and forgot I was supposed to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not because it's an interface that you'd get `class1`, but because `getClass()` will resolve to the runtime class of the instance. Since you've created it as a `class1`, that's the runtime type. Won't give you a compile-time error.

Getting a `Class` object for an interface is possible via reflection.

Alternatively you can access the class more directly through the `class` keyword:

```
String className = Runnable.class.getName();
```

Comment: So basically, if I have an interface use the getClass() method it will always return the class of whatever I have defined the interface to be an instance of?

Comment: @Erik That's right. Because getClass() gets resolved to the implementation of the instance's class. It's dynamically resolved, not something statically determined at compile time. Thanks for the edit, user268396, that is indeed more direct. Sorry if I stop making sense, getting a bit tired.